# Why Web Page is showing a horizontal scroll bar even it fits on the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have create this web page and It fits  in the browser perfectly. But There is this horizontal scroll bar to navigate horizontally. There cannot be horizontal bar if the site fits to the screen properly.

I checked if I have accidentally zoomed webpage by browser. I checked even with different browsers. But it all shows the same...

Here's the screenshot of the web page:

[image]

Here's my code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Omicron.com</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">



<style>

/*#MostUpperGreyLine img{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 10px;
    height:auto;
}*/
#Header-New img{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 10px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top:-5px; 
}

</style>

</head>
<body>


    <!--<div id="MostUpperGreyLine">
        <img src="MostUpperGreyLine.png" alt="No Green Header Found!">
    </div>-->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="HomePage.html" style="font-family:N-Gage;font-size:15px;">Omicron.Inc</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Our Softwares <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Software 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Software 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Software 3</a></li>
                            <!--<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>-->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                </form>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <!--<li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>-->
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>


    <div id="Header-New">
        <img src="Header-New.png" alt="Header not Found!">
    </div>  



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="square.png" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have marked the vertical scrollbar in red, but you are mentioning the horizontal one, which one do you need to disappear?

Comment: @JiFus: Not I marked the space reserved by the Horizontal Scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove margin-left and margin-right for .row and it well be fixed.

Comment: No Sir, it is still the same

Comment: @user7980830 i checked your code again and noticed you add margin to row class. try this new solution.

Comment: Which **.row** are you talking about?

Comment: @user7980830 The last one. before script tags.

Comment: No Sir, I haven't use any margin-left or margin-right for those columns.

Comment: add  .row{   margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px; } 
let me know if it works . i fixed problem on my end with these styles.

Comment: Here's my css looks like for the problem you assumed:

**.col-md-4, .col-sm-6,  {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}**